# i need help there's wrong in my codes and to improved my codes?

Tags: c, stdio

input 0,0,0,0 output no entry insert , 
input 1,1,1,1 ouput all entry insert,
input 1,1,1,0 ouput three inserted entry,
input 1,0,1,0 ouput gate 1 and gate 3/ input 1,1,0,0 output gate 1,gate 2,
input 1,0,1,0 output two entry insert

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int n1,n2,n3,n4;
    printf ("Enter 1st number : ");
    scanf ("%d",&n1);
    printf ("Enter 2nd number : ");
    scanf ("%d",&n2);
    printf ("Enter 3rd number : ");
    scanf ("%d",&n3);
    printf ("Enter 4th number : ");
    scanf ("%d",&n4);
    if (n1==0)
    {
        if (n2==0)
        {
            printf ("no entry inserted\n");
        }
    }
    if (n3>0)
    {
        if (n1%2==0)
        {
            if (n2%2==0)
            {
                printf (" three inserted entry");
            }
        }
        if (n1%2!=0)
        {
            if (n3%2!=0)
            {

                printf ("all entry inserted");
            }
        }
    }
    if (n3>0)
    {
        if (n2%3==0)
        {
            if (n2%2==0)
            {
                printf ("two inserted entery");
            }
        }
        if (n1%2!=0)
        {
            if (n3%4!=4)
            {
                printf ("gate 1 and gate 2 and gate 3");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

input 0,0,0,0 output no entry inserted ,
 input 1,1,1,1 ouput all entry inserted,
input 1,1,1,0 ouput three  inserted,
input 1,0,1,0 ouput gate 1 and gate 3/ input 1,1,0,0 output gate 1,gate 2
input 1,0,1,0 output two inserted entry

Comment: What is this supposed to do? You're going to have to explain what the problem is because I have no idea what's wrong, or even what's right.

Comment: can you please translate your question to english ?

Comment: I think I know what do you want I'll post code in a second.

Comment: This is not valid C: `main() {`...

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline Looks valid to me.  There's an implicit `int` return type for ANSI C89.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the code, but your question is unclear so I went with my interpretation here. But this 1,0,1,0 was mention 2 times so I used i only once.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
 int n1,n2,n3,n4;
    printf ("Enter 1st number : ");
    scanf ("%d",&n1);
    printf ("Enter 2nd number : ");
    scanf ("%d",&n2);
    printf ("Enter 3rd number : ");
    scanf ("%d",&n3);
    printf ("Enter 4th number : ");
    scanf ("%d",&n4);
 if(!n1&&!n2&&!n3&&!n4){
   printf("no entry inserted");
   return 0;
 }
 else if(n1&&n2&&n3&&n4){
   printf("all entry inserted");
   return 0;
 }
 else if(n1&&n2&&n3&&!n4){
   printf("three inserted entry");
   return 0;
 }
 else if(n1&&!n2&&n3&&!n4){
   printf("ouput gate 1 and gate 3");
   return 0;
 }
 else if(n1&&n2&&!n3&&!n4){
   printf("output gate 1,gate 2");
   return 0;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could also use `int n = (n1 << 3) | (n2 << 2) | (n3 << 1) | (n4 << 0);` then check for specific values of `n` (`0x0`, `0xF`, `0x1`, `0x5`, `0x3`)